# What is the default text padding in spinner

Tags: android

I have a spinner and a textview with style like spinner. I want to align the text in both, but I do not know how much padding the text in the spinner has.

[image]

Comment: I think it should be between 5-10dp

Comment: I tried 10dp, but it looks like it is more. I can keep trying until it looks ok, but I prefer to be exact :)

Comment: It is hard to find the exact padding but more imp is to give perfect effect on any resolution whatever the padding is.

Comment: I made a custom spinner addapter and set the paddingLeft to 15dp. And set the padding to the TextView to 15dp. This way I made sure they are the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One thing that you could find in [Android Styles](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) is,

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem" parent="Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item>
</style>
```

It shows padding is **`8dp`** each on **`start`** and **`end`**.

**Note:** If 8dp look lesser to you, may be you should also look for padding on spinner itself. Like `Padding of Spinner item + Padinng of text = What you want`.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 

//simple_spinner_item Specify the spinner TextView

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// simple_spinner_dropdown_item Specify the dropdown item TextView if not set , and the same as simple_spinner_item  
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get paddings from Spinner:

```
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);

        int leftPadding = spinner.getPaddingLeft();
        int topPadding = spinner.getPaddingTop();
        int rightPadding = spinner.getPaddingRight();
        int bottomPadding = spinner.getPaddingBottom();
```